# Google colab to neo4j database connectivity error: service unavailable

Tags: python, neo4j

I am trying to connect my google colab notebook to neo4j server, using neo4j driver package that is officially supported by neo4j. BI am getting  the following error.
ServiceUnavailable: Couldn't connect to 127.0.0.1:7687 (resolved to ('127.0.0.1:7687',)):
Failed to establish connection to ResolvedIPv4Address(('127.0.0.1', 7687)) (reason [Errno 111] Connection refused)
This is my full stack trace:

```
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/neo4j/io/__init__.py in _connect(resolved_address, timeout, keep_alive)
   1175         log.debug("[#0000]  C: <OPEN> %s", resolved_address)
-> 1176         s.connect(resolved_address)
   1177         s.settimeout(t)

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
9 frames
ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection to ResolvedIPv4Address(('127.0.0.1', 7687)) (reason [Errno 111] Connection refused)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/neo4j/io/__init__.py in connect(address, timeout, custom_resolver, ssl_context, keep_alive)
   1316                 "\n".join(map(str, errors))
   1317             )
-> 1318         ) from errors[0]
   1319 
   1320 

ServiceUnavailable: Couldn't connect to 127.0.0.1:7687 (resolved to ('127.0.0.1:7687',)):
Failed to establish connection to ResolvedIPv4Address(('127.0.0.1', 7687)) (reason [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, well, you can't connect to localhost from Google Colab, because the localhost for the notebook is completely different than your machine IP. Either expose your localhost outwardly, or create a VM on a cloud, or use a Neo4j Sandbox version, which is already exposed to the internet: https://neo4j.com/sandbox/

Comment: will it work if instead of using "localhost", I use my machie's IPv4 address?

Comment: if you have exposed your 7687 port